# Lost wordpress login URL

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to find a way to recover the lost login URL. Its not the default URL anymore. I want a way to change the login URL in the database or in the file system but I can't find where to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you switch it via .htaccess or by renaming the files?

Comment: Not sure its not my site, but I need to make amendments to the website.

Answer (score 0):

Open phpmyadmin -> DB ->wp_options -> Here you find the ur site urls.
Hope this help for you.

Comment: What is the name of the field?

Answer (score -1):

For recover the lost login URL follow mention steps:

1. Open phpmyadmin.
2. select your database.
3. Open wp_option table.
4. See option_name and option_value column
5. Search "siteurl" and "home" in "option_name" column
6. Change URL according to your requirement.

Hope its helpful..